# Unexpected Outcome When Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wy4wd/19/

I am parsing a json object but it's falling through to the else which results in the html being `Error` when it should be `ID not found` and I can't figure out why.

It works fine if `success` is `1`.

The JSON is returned by a post request but for question purposes I am declaring it locally.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = '{"success": "0","patient_cid": "0"}';
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    if (response.success == 0) {
        if (response.patient_cid == 0) {            
            $('#resultpanel').html('<p>ID not found</p>');
        }
        if (response.patient_ambassador == 0) {                 
            $('#resultpanel').html('<p>ID found but not an ambassador</p>');
        }               
        if (response.soap_error == '1') {                   
            $('#resultpanel').html('<p>SOAP error</p>').fadeIn('slow');
        }                   
    }
    if (response.success == 1){
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>success</p>').fadeIn('slow');
    }   
    else {              
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>Error</p>').fadeIn('slow');
    }   
});
```

Comment: One sidenote: Should the `success` code really be wrapped as a string? Shouldn't it just be  `"success": 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
//... previous code here
else if (response.success == 1){
//... the rest of the code here
```

if I understand you correctly.

Otherwise the first error parsing will be executed but replaced with the code in the last else statement.

Comment: damnit, I can't believe that. Thanks for saving my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the parsing of the JSON, it's the logic in the `if` statement that causes that.

The panel is actually set to "ID not found" for a short while, but then you replace it with "Error".

Put the `else` where you handle the `success == 0` first, and use `else if` to make a chain of conditions:

```
if (response.success == 0) {
    if (response.patient_cid == 0) {            
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>ID not found</p>');
    }
    else if (response.patient_ambassador == 0) {                 
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>ID found but not an ambassador</p>');
    }               
    else if (response.soap_error == '1') {                   
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>SOAP error</p>').fadeIn('slow');
    }                   
    else {              
        $('#resultpanel').html('<p>Error</p>').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}
if (response.success == 1){
    $('#resultpanel').html('<p>success</p>').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the value being set to what you want but then is being reset to Error by this line
`$('#resultpanel').html('<p>Error</p>').fadeIn('slow');`

You should understand how false-y and truth-y work in javascript: 
I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = '{"success": "0","patient_cid": "0"}',
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
    message;

    if (response.success == '1') {
        message = 'success';
    }
    else {
        if (response.patient_cid == '0') {            
            message = 'ID not found';
        }
        else if (response.patient_ambassador == '0') {
            message = 'ID found but not an ambassador';                 
        }               
        else if (response.soap_error == '1') {
            message = 'SOAP error';                              
        }
        else {              
            message = 'Error';                              
        }   
    }   
    $('#resultpanel').html('<p>' + message + '</p>').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: `"0"` is not falsy! The data in the JSON should be numeric for this to work: `{"success":0,"patient_cid":0}`